# How to convert string to json sequentially

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-mvc, linkedhashmap

```
public void addNewUser(MongoClient mdbClient, String newUserName, String  newUserPassword, DBManagement.DBRole roles) {
      
    System.out.println("inside addNEw User method");
    Map<String, String> user = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    user.put("createUser", newUserName);
    user.put("pwd", newUserPassword); 
    List<Map<String, String>> listOfRoles = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> role1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    role1.put("role",roles.getRole());
    role1.put("db", roles.getDb());
    listOfRoles.add(role1);
    user.put("roles", listOfRoles.toString());
    System.out.println("MAP: " + user);

    try{
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user);
        /*String json = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(user);*/
        System.out.println(json);
        //String jsonCommand = "{ createUser: \" + newUserName +"/" + " ," + "pwd: /" + newUserPassword + "/" + " ,"  + "roles : [" + roles_str + "]}" ;
        String jsonCommand = json;
        System.out.println("createUserString-->"+jsonCommand);
        Document command  = new Document(Document.parse(jsonCommand));
        Document collStatsResults = mdbClient.getDatabase("admin").runCommand(command);
        System.out.println(collStatsResults.toJson());
    } catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error " + e);
    }
}
```

I am getting output string as -`{"createUser":"demoUser2","pwd":"password","roles":"[{role=dbOwner, db=udata}]"}`

Expected output- `{"createUser":"demoUser2","pwd":"password","roles":[{"role":"dbOwner", "db":"udata"}]}`

Firstly i used JSONObject() but it doesnt care about the json sequence ,so i tried with linkedhashMap but facing array conversion issue..can anyone help.Or is there any other way to generate json sequentially.

Comment: Try just not using the `toString` on `listOfRoles`.

Comment: And explain what didn't work with JSONObject. What does "doesnt care about the json sequence" mean?